# Selecting a row based on values from multiple rows

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have an sql table like this

```
Id  Idea        Trigger
1   CoreOne     Trig1
2   CoreOne     Trig2
3   CorePlus    Trig3
4   CorePlus    Trig1
5   CorePP      Trig4
```

Basically, each idea has a trigger. Each idea can have more than one trigger and each trigger can be used to trigger more than one idea. But all triggers have to be present for the idea to launch.

From another table, I get this.

```
Id  ArmNum  Trigger
1   123 Trig1
2   123 Trig2
```

Each arm produces triggers. I need to now match the two tables and be able to tell that for Arm 123, Idea, CoreOne can be launched because both the triggers are present. But CorePlus cannot be because it need Trig3.

Any ideas. I seem totally lost on this one.

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you added few (3-4) more elements to your sample data. Few more triggers, few more ideas, few more arms that would illustrate various cases. And then show how the final result should look like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your data and it looks like your sample data doesn't illustrate various scenarios, but the following would work or would be a good starting point to work with.

```
GO
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (Id int, Idea varchar(100), [Trigger] varchar(100))
DECLARE @t2 TABLE (Id int, ArmNum int, [Trigger] varchar(100))
DECLARE @t4 TABLE (Id int, Idea varchar(100), ArmNum int, [Trigger] varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1,'CoreOne','Trig1'), (2,'CoreOne','Trig2'),(3,'CorePlus','Trig3'), (4,'CorePlus', 'Trig1'),(5, 'CorePP', 'Trig4')
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES (1, 123, 'Trig1'), (2,123,'Trig2')

INSERT INTO @t4
SELECT t1.id, t1.idea, t2.ArmNum, t2.[Trigger]
FROM @t1 t1
LEFT JOIN @t2 t2 on t1.[Trigger] =t2.[Trigger]

SELECT DISTINCT idea, ArmNum, 'Y' [Launch?] FROM @t4
WHERE idea NOT IN (SELECT idea FROM @t4 where armNum IS NULL)
GO
```